# Error 404 in URL for encrypt with Google KMS

Tags: google-cloud-kms

I'm following the tutorial to encrypt data with google cloud kms, but when I try to encryt give me 404 error. I seach in the code and noted that it has DEFAULT_ROOT_URL = https://cloudkms.googleapis.com/. but the root of the url do not appears  in the URL, then of couse give error 404. Could someone tell me why the URL was not mounted corretilly. I look in properties and there is no reference for Root_URL.

`

The requested URL `/v1beta1/projects/condoease-3f3ea/locations/global/keyRings/test/cryptoKeys/quickstart:encrypt` was not found on this server.  That?s all we know.

```
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at com.example.getstarted.util.CloudKeyManagementServiceHelper.wrapDataEncryptionKey(CloudKeyManagementServiceHelper.java:129)
at com.example.getstarted.util.CloudStorageHelper.getImageUrl(CloudStorageHelper.java:121)
at com.example.getstarted.basicactions.CreateBookServlet.doPost(CreateBookServlet.java:56)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689)
at com.example.getstarted.util.DatastoreSessionFilter.doFilter(DatastoreSessionFilter.java:111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

`

Comment: It is the gettingstar JAVA.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/kms has a good sample to get you started. I don't think the getting-started-java has KMS samples (that I know of).

What version of the library are you using?
Your URL is using /v1beta1/ which makes me think you're using an older version. Cloud KMS is GA and should be /v1/.

*Update*:

Full disclosure I'm an engineer @ Google on Cloud KMS.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-bookshelf-java-cloud-kms looks like it has instructions to download a legacy java client library which is constructing broken URLs to v1beta1. We've filed an issue internally to track getting this resolved ASAP, thank you for posting your issue!

In the meantime, I'd encourage the above github [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/kms) to get you started using KMS. Thanks for using the product!

Answer (score 0):

API version `v1beta1` is no longer supported; can you tell us where you found it documented? I'd like to get it fixed.

You'll also get this uninformative error message if you err in other part of the URLs, such as missing the fixed components like `/projects/`, `/locations/`, `/keyRings/`, or `/cryptoKeys/`. We'll look at improving it.

Comment: I'm doing this tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-bookshelf-java-cloud-kms/index.html.   Clone this repo: git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java.git and the rest of the code was in this bucket: gs://gcp-kms-codelab/Step7/*

Comment: Thanks so much! We've filed a bug to clean up that obsolete documentation.